# How to implement this pattern in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, unity-game-engine, observer-pattern

```
Class Client{
  main(){
    MyRequest m = new MyRequest();
    m.function();
  }
  onSucess(string s){
    Debug.log("i get data from network:"+s);
  }
}
Class Network{
   sendMyrequest(MyRequest r){
     Thread thread = new Thread(() => sendMyrequestTask(r));
     thread.start(); 
   }
   private void sendMyrequestTask(MyRequest r){
     if(...){
        //call delegate function onSucess(string s)
     }
   }
}
Class MyRequest{
private Network network;
  function(){
    //do something
    network.sendMyrequest(MyRequest r);

  }

}
```

in this case, callback function onSucess(string s) should be a delegate, or a interface, how and where should I implement it? Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!!

Edit: this problem is like: A call B,B call C, when C's job is done, C should call A. How to implement this?

Thanks all guys. I implement in this way.

```
public interface CallbackFunction{
   public onSucess(string s);
}
Class Client:CallbackFunction{
  main(){
    MyRequest m = new MyRequest();
    m.function(this);
  }
  onSucess(string s){
    Debug.log("i get data from network:"+s);
  }
}
Class Network{
   sendMyrequest(MyRequest r,CallbackFunction c){
     Thread thread = new Thread(() => sendMyrequestTask(r,c));
     thread.start(); 
   }
   private void sendMyrequestTask(MyRequest r,CallbackFunction c){
     if(...){
        //call delegate function onSucess(string s)
        c.onSucess("bla bla bla");
     }
   }
}
Class MyRequest{
private Network network;
  function(CallbackFunction c){
    //do something
    network.sendMyrequest(this,c);

  }

}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use `Task<T>` and `async` / `await`.

Comment: I know, Task<T> will be wrote in sendMyrequest(). My problem is how to write the delegate onSucess().

Comment: You don't.  The whole point of `Task<T>` is to encapsulate an asynchronous result.  Learn about promises.

Comment: it's not a asynchronous problem. We can assume it return immediately.

Comment: If you assume that it returns immediately, then why are you creating a thread to do it in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [`Action<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate as a constructor argument in `MyRequest` we can achieve something like this.

You can replace the `Action<>` type with any other delegate you might want to use. `Action<>` or `Func<>` should cover just about anything.

By the way, your code, and hence my code below is *not* the observer pattern.

```
public class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MyRequest(OnSuccess);
        client.Function();
        //Output:
        //I'm in the callback
        //Foo.Bar()
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void OnSuccess(string result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm in the callback");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

}

public class Network
{
    public void SendMyRequest(MyRequest request)
    {
        var result = "Foo.Bar()";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            request.SuccessCallback(result);
        }
    }
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public Action<string> SuccessCallback { get; private set; }
    private Network _network;

    public MyRequest(Action<string> successCallback)
    {
        _network = new Network();
        SuccessCallback = successCallback;
    }
    public void Function()
    {
        _network.SendMyRequest(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`async` and `await.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async)

For more info :

Many methods do not immediately return. A method may need to query an external source. This takes time. With async and await, we formalize and clarify how asynchronous, non-blocking methods begin and end.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx

Comment: I update my question. My question is not a async / await problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to implement something similar to [WebClient.DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Which uses following delegate type:

```
public delegate void DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
    Object sender
    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)`
```

with following usage pattern:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCallback2;
client.DownloadStringAsync (new Uri(address));
```

Note: if you don't expect multiple listeners using `async`/`await` will lead to much easier to understand code.